# How do I specify which php file to open in command prompt?

Tags: php, xampp

I'm creating a website project using php through xampp. I've followed through a tutorial online and have opened up my website through localhost:8000. My question is, when I open a php file through command prompt, how do I specify which file I want to be opened? (at the moment index.php is the file that is opened). Screenshot below.

[Files and command prompt screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD8gf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a PHP file through the command prompt you type:

```
php nameOfFile.php
```

That isn't what you are doing. You're running the PHP [built in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). It doesn't open *index.php*, it starts a web server.

When you request a URL from that server from your browser (or other HTTP client) then it will map the path of that URL onto a file.

i.e. if you type *http://localhost:8000/foo.php* then it will run *foo.php* and return the result in the HTTP response.

If you request a directory, then it will try to map that onto a file called *index.php* in that directory.